# in qpython, how do I enter a "return" character

Tags: qpython

Very basic question. Im trying to use qpython. I can type things in the console but no obvious way to enter a return (or enter)

Comment: Generally, the console is single line inputs only. Create a script in the editor.

Comment: If you found my answer satisfactory, please mark it as a solution. :-)

Answer (score 2):

go to settings->input method select word-based

Comment: How does this answer the question?

Comment: Actually that does answer the question. It did what i needed. When it wasn't in word based mode there was no enter key, only next. In word based mode the enter key appeared

Answer (score 0):

The console works just like a normally python console. You can use a function if you want to write a script in the console.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way of doing it. 
The console will automatically input a break line when the line of code ends so you can continue inputting in the screen without any scroll bars.
For complex code, you should use the editor.

Answer (score -1):

Would a newline character solve your problem?

```
s = "line 1\n line 2"
print(s)
```

Should print out

```
line 1
line 2
```

If that's what you're looking for? It's called an escape - Python has other ones for tab, etc.